# Flutter: Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform | cloudfirestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch data from the cloud filestore to a Text widget. I did fetch Querysnapshot document data from cloud firestore and show that data in the text widget. but it shows the mentioned error.

```
body: SafeArea(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                final messages = snapshot.data!.docs;
                List<Text> messageWidgets = [];
                for (var message in messages) {
                  final messageText = message.get('text');
                  final senderText = message.get('sender');

                  final messageWidget = Text('$messageText from $senderText');

                  messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
                }
                return Column(
                  children: messageWidgets,
                );
              }
              return Text("No widget to build");
            },
          ),
          Container(
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(child: TextField(
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    messageText = value;
                  },
                )),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _firestore.collection('messages').add(
                        {'text': messageText, 'sender': LoggedInUser.email});
                  },
                  child: Text("Send"),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

I am able to print the data by using:

```
 Print(message.data());
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The error you mentioned in the title says it all: some of your data probably is missing some fields you're looking for.

I can see you're extracting the `text` and `sender` keys. This means that for some `message` in your loop, i.e. for some document in your Firestore database, one of those two keys is missing.

As you said, use `print(message.data());` to investigate where and why.

Just be sure to put that `print` statement just below the `if(snapshot.hasData)` so that you will print to the console before it throws the `BadState` exception.